# Где находится файл конфигурации .NET уровня компьютера или сервера?

Tags: windows, .net

Где находится файл конфигурации (.config) уровня компьютера или сервера?

Comment: [MSDN: .NET Framework - файлы конфигурации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AlexKrass: А почему не ответ? На SO комментарий в ответ не конвертируется.

Comment: @VladD, нашел нужную ссылку секунд за 30 и закинул, поэтому не посчитал нужным давать как ответ. А с новой системой SO я еще пока только знакомлюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл machine.config находится в папке `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[ver]\Config`
Где ver - номер сборки инсталлированной системы.

Comment: Круто. Не успел. Надо ответ сразу давать. :)

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от версии, но можете поискать здесь:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```